# Spark - use regexp_replace to replace multiple groups

Tags: regex, string, scala, apache-spark, regexp-replace

In Spark, I have a dataframe with one column having data in the following format: "***he=1she=2it=3me=4***". I want to convert that column into the format "***1-2-3-4***".

```
val rawDF = Seq(
  ("he=1she=2it=3me=4"),
  ("he=3she=5it=9me=7")
).toDF("raw")

val newDF = rawDF.withColumn("converted",  regexp_replace($"raw", """[\D]*(\d*)[\D]*(\d*)[\D]*(\d*)[\D]*(\d*)""", """$1-$2-$3-$4"""))
```

Then I got the result with added '-'s at the end. I do not know why this happen.

```
+-----------------+----------+
|              raw| converted|
+-----------------+----------+
|he=1she=2it=3me=4|1-2-3-4---|
|he=3she=5it=9me=7|3-5-9-7---|
+-----------------+----------+
```

My expected result is

```
+-----------------+----------+
|              raw| converted|
+-----------------+----------+
|he=1she=2it=3me=4|   1-2-3-4|
|he=3she=5it=9me=7|   3-5-9-7|
+-----------------+----------+
```

Could you please help explain, what was wrong with my code?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to just replace `[a-z]+` with nothing, and then replace `=` with `-`.

Comment: Thanks CAustin. That will work after removing the heading =, otherwise I will get -1-2-3-4

Comment: Replacing each `[\D]*(\d*)` with `[\D]*=(\d*)` should give the wanted result.

Comment: Thank you @LeoC. That works. Even replacing just the first one also work.
Replacing [\D]*(\d*) with [\D]*(\d+) also works.